# IconButton Hovering Effect on Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, hover, icons, iconbutton

below i have different icons from material UI , which currently displays a grey circle whenever i hover on any of them , i want to remove this grey circle and i want each icon to change to a specific color whenever i hover over it i looked at the documentation in material ui but couldn't find anything that explains it , appreciate your feedback.

```
<Box className={classes.socialmedia}>
            <IconButton aria-label="twitter">
              <TwitterIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton aria-label="facebook">
              <FacebookIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton aria-label="instagram">
              <InstagramIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton aria-label="Youtube">
              <YouTubeIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton aria-label="Apple">
              <AppleIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Box>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to remove the grey circle displaying in background on hover then you can use `disableFocusRipple` & `disableRipple` property in **IconButton** component and set `style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}`.
Ex:

```
<IconButton
    disableFocusRipple
    disableRipple
    style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
    aria-label="twitter"
  >
    <TwitterIcon className={classes.twitter} />
  </IconButton>
```

To change the color of icon on hover then use `hover` selector.
Ex:

```
    const useStyles = makeStyles({
  twitter: {
    "&:hover": {
      color: "#00acee"
    }
  }
});
```

I've created a quick example to illustrate the solution in codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-ramanujan-wnj9fw?file=/index.js:948-961

Answer (score 0):

Define a hook. Import `makeStyle` from `'@material-ui/core/styles'`.

```
const useStyles = makeStyle(() => ({
  styleRed: {
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: '#f00'
    }
  },
  styleBlue: {
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: '#00f'
    }
  }
}));
```

Then in your component:

```
// using our hook
const {styleRed, styleBlue} = useStyles();

// some more code

return (
  <>
    <IconButton aria-label="twitter" classes={styleRed}>
      <TwitterIcon />
    </IconButton>
    <IconButton aria-label="facebook" classes={styleBlue}>
      <FacebookIcon />
    </IconButton>
  </>
)
```